# Rails loop through inserted variable from database to url for external call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, spree, httparty, solidus

I'm trying to show the line_items of an order from Solidus into the Items table in my rails app. Previously I saved the orders from Solidus to my "Order" (in my app) table with attribute "order_number"

I need to insert the order_number into the url I'm using for the external call using httparty and loop through all the rows in order_number to show the attributes of each order in my index view. Each order, for example: http://localhost:4000/api/orders/R984044507.json?token=fd5a8b4b294303ad52fcb19a9eaf8bb7325d20a8aa5abbc7
has a structure like this:

```
 {
"id": 3,
"number": "R984044507",
"item_total": "59.97",
"total": "68.22",
"ship_total": "5.0",
"state": "complete",
"adjustment_total": "3.25",
"user_id": null,
"created_at": "2017-07-09T17:12:19.209Z",
"updated_at": "2017-07-09T17:14:24.657Z",
"completed_at": "2017-07-09T17:14:24.657Z",
"payment_total": "0.0",
"shipment_state": "pending",
"payment_state": "balance_due",
"email": "ignaciosm@gmail.com",
"special_instructions": null,
"channel": "spree",
"included_tax_total": "0.0",
"additional_tax_total": "3.25",
"display_included_tax_total": "$0.00",
"display_additional_tax_total": "$3.25",
"tax_total": "3.25",
"currency": "USD",
"covered_by_store_credit": false,
"display_total_applicable_store_credit": "$0.00",
"order_total_after_store_credit": "68.22",
"display_order_total_after_store_credit": "$68.22",
"total_applicable_store_credit": "0.0",
"display_total_available_store_credit": "$0.00",
"display_store_credit_remaining_after_capture": "$0.00",
"canceler_id": null,
"display_item_total": "$59.97",
"total_quantity": 3,
"display_total": "$68.22",
"display_ship_total": "$5.00",
"display_tax_total": "$3.25",
"token": "vQyNyoZEdjOux5XYOCdafg",
"checkout_steps": [],
"payment_methods": [],
"bill_address": {},
"ship_address": {},
"line_items": [
{
"id": 3,
"quantity": 1,
"price": "19.99",
"variant_id": 17,
"variant": {
"product_id": 3,
"id": 17,
"name": "Ruby on Rails Baseball Jersey",
"sku": "ROR-00008",
"price": "19.99",
"weight": "0.0",
"height": null,
"width": null,
"depth": null,
"is_master": false,
"slug": "ruby-on-rails-baseball-jersey",
"description": "Fuga quia cumque sunt dignissimos eum unde dicta doloribus. Iste sit inventore doloribus et aut eum totam nisi. Ut quas explicabo omnis eos ipsa consequuntur. Aut a quis molestiae reprehenderit suscipit expedita.",
"track_inventory": true,
"cost_price": "17.0",
"option_values": [
{
"id": 3,
"name": "Large",
"presentation": "L",
"option_type_name": "tshirt-size",
"option_type_id": 1,
"option_type_presentation": "Size"
},
{
"id": 7,
"name": "Blue",
"presentation": "Blue",
"option_type_name": "tshirt-color",
"option_type_id": 2,
"option_type_presentation": "Color"
}
],
"images": [
{
"id": 15,
"position": 1,
"attachment_content_type": "image/png",
"attachment_file_name": "ror_baseball_jersey_blue.png",
"type": "Spree::Image",
"attachment_updated_at": "2017-07-08T23:10:54.595Z",
"attachment_width": 240,
"attachment_height": 240,
"alt": null,
"viewable_type": "Spree::Variant",
"viewable_id": 17,
"mini_url": "/spree/products/15/mini/ror_baseball_jersey_blue.png?1499555454",
"small_url": "/spree/products/15/small/ror_baseball_jersey_blue.png?1499555454",
"product_url": "/spree/products/15/product/ror_baseball_jersey_blue.png?1499555454",
"large_url": "/spree/products/15/large/ror_baseball_jersey_blue.png?1499555454"
},
{
"id": 16,
"position": 2,
"attachment_content_type": "image/png",
"attachment_file_name": "ror_baseball_jersey_back_blue.png",
"type": "Spree::Image",
"attachment_updated_at": "2017-07-08T23:10:55.123Z",
"attachment_width": 240,
"attachment_height": 240,
"alt": null,
"viewable_type": "Spree::Variant",
"viewable_id": 17,
"mini_url": "/spree/products/16/mini/ror_baseball_jersey_back_blue.png?1499555455",
"small_url": "/spree/products/16/small/ror_baseball_jersey_back_blue.png?1499555455",
"product_url": "/spree/products/16/product/ror_baseball_jersey_back_blue.png?1499555455",
"large_url": "/spree/products/16/large/ror_baseball_jersey_back_blue.png?1499555455"
}
],
"display_price": "$19.99",
"options_text": "Size: L, Color: Blue",
"in_stock": true,
"is_backorderable": true,
"total_on_hand": 9,
"is_destroyed": false
},
"adjustments": [
{
"id": 5,
"source_type": "Spree::TaxRate",
"source_id": 1,
"adjustable_type": "Spree::LineItem",
"adjustable_id": 3,
"amount": "1.0",
"label": "North America 5.000%",
"promotion_code": null,
"eligible": true,
"created_at": "2017-07-09T17:13:56.297Z",
"updated_at": "2017-07-09T17:14:24.280Z",
"display_amount": "$1.00"
}
],
"single_display_amount": "$19.99",
"display_amount": "$19.99",
"total": "20.99"
},
{
"id": 4,
"quantity": 1,
"price": "19.99",
"variant_id": 6,
"variant": {
"product_id": 6,
"id": 6,
"name": "Ruby Baseball Jersey",
"sku": "RUB-00001",
"price": "19.99",
"weight": "0.0",
"height": null,
"width": null,
"depth": null,
"is_master": true,
"slug": "ruby-baseball-jersey",
"description": "Fuga quia cumque sunt dignissimos eum unde dicta doloribus. Iste sit inventore doloribus et aut eum totam nisi. Ut quas explicabo omnis eos ipsa consequuntur. Aut a quis molestiae reprehenderit suscipit expedita.",
"track_inventory": true,
"cost_price": "17.0",
"option_values": [],
"images": [
{
"id": 34,
"position": 1,
"attachment_content_type": "image/png",
"attachment_file_name": "ruby_baseball.png",
"type": "Spree::Image",
"attachment_updated_at": "2017-07-08T23:11:04.206Z",
"attachment_width": 495,
"attachment_height": 477,
"alt": null,
"viewable_type": "Spree::Variant",
"viewable_id": 6,
"mini_url": "/spree/products/34/mini/ruby_baseball.png?1499555464",
"small_url": "/spree/products/34/small/ruby_baseball.png?1499555464",
"product_url": "/spree/products/34/product/ruby_baseball.png?1499555464",
"large_url": "/spree/products/34/large/ruby_baseball.png?1499555464"
}
],
"display_price": "$19.99",
"options_text": "",
"in_stock": true,
"is_backorderable": true,
"total_on_hand": 9,
"is_destroyed": false
},
"adjustments": [
{
"id": 6,
"source_type": "Spree::TaxRate",
"source_id": 1,
"adjustable_type": "Spree::LineItem",
"adjustable_id": 4,
"amount": "1.0",
"label": "North America 5.000%",
"promotion_code": null,
"eligible": true,
"created_at": "2017-07-09T17:13:56.327Z",
"updated_at": "2017-07-09T17:14:24.300Z",
"display_amount": "$1.00"
}
],
"single_display_amount": "$19.99",
"display_amount": "$19.99",
"total": "20.99"
},
{
"id": 5,
"quantity": 1,
"price": "19.99",
"variant_id": 7,
"variant": {
"product_id": 7,
"id": 7,
"name": "Apache Baseball Jersey",
"sku": "APC-00001",
"price": "19.99",
"weight": "0.0",
"height": null,
"width": null,
"depth": null,
"is_master": true,
"slug": "apache-baseball-jersey",
"description": "Fuga quia cumque sunt dignissimos eum unde dicta doloribus. Iste sit inventore doloribus et aut eum totam nisi. Ut quas explicabo omnis eos ipsa consequuntur. Aut a quis molestiae reprehenderit suscipit expedita.",
"track_inventory": true,
"cost_price": "17.0",
"option_values": [],
"images": [
{
"id": 33,
"position": 1,
"attachment_content_type": "image/png",
"attachment_file_name": "apache_baseball.png",
"type": "Spree::Image",
"attachment_updated_at": "2017-07-08T23:11:03.616Z",
"attachment_width": 504,
"attachment_height": 484,
"alt": null,
"viewable_type": "Spree::Variant",
"viewable_id": 7,
"mini_url": "/spree/products/33/mini/apache_baseball.png?1499555463",
"small_url": "/spree/products/33/small/apache_baseball.png?1499555463",
"product_url": "/spree/products/33/product/apache_baseball.png?1499555463",
"large_url": "/spree/products/33/large/apache_baseball.png?1499555463"
}
],
"display_price": "$19.99",
"options_text": "",
"in_stock": true,
"is_backorderable": true,
"total_on_hand": 9,
"is_destroyed": false
},
"adjustments": [
{
"id": 7,
"source_type": "Spree::TaxRate",
"source_id": 1,
"adjustable_type": "Spree::LineItem",
"adjustable_id": 5,
"amount": "1.0",
"label": "North America 5.000%",
"promotion_code": null,
"eligible": true,
"created_at": "2017-07-09T17:13:56.337Z",
"updated_at": "2017-07-09T17:14:24.313Z",
"display_amount": "$1.00"
}
],
"single_display_amount": "$19.99",
"display_amount": "$19.99",
"total": "20.99"
}
]
}
```

here is my controller:

```
# items controller      
     def index
          order_number = 'R984044507' # just to test until I figure out how to loop through order_ids
          url = 'http://localhost:4000/api/orders/'
          key = '.json?token=fd5a8b4b294303ad52fcb19a9eaf8bb7325d20a8aa5abbc7'
          response = HTTParty.get(url+order_number+key)

          @items = response.parsed_response    
      end
```

My Index looks like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Order</th>
      <th>Variand_Id</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <% (@items['line_items']).each do |item| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= @items['number'] %></td>
        <td><%= item['variant']["id"] %></td>
        <td><%= item['variant']["name"] %></td>
        <td><%= item['variant']['price'] %></td>
        <td><%= item["quantity"] %></td>

      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

I hard coded the order number of one of the orders in my Orders table to test that it shows the items in each order, but I don't know how to loop through the orders so I get the items from every order.

I'm not sure my approach is the best, I'm a beginner. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What order ids you want to loop? All of them? You need to get the ids before you can loop them (maybe using another API endpoint).

Comment: Yes, I already got them and saved them to my Orders table (all pending orders in Solidus)....so for my question assume the orders I want to look are all the orders on my Orders table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

#### Controller

```
def index
  orders = Order.all.pluck(:number)

  @items = []
  orders.each do |order|
    order_number = order
    url = 'http://localhost:4000/api/orders/'
    key = '.json?token=fd5a8b4b294303ad52fcb19a9eaf8bb7325d20a8aa5abbc7'
    response = HTTParty.get(url+order_number+key)

    @items << response.parsed_response
  end
end
```

First you get all order numbers (i assume that `number` is the column name in `orders` table) and then you loop through them, requesting each order and adding its attributes to `@items` array.

#### View

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Order</th>
      <th>Variand_Id</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @items.each do |item| %>
      <% item['line_items'].each do |line_item| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= item['number'] %></td>
          <td><%= line_item['variant']["id"] %></td>
          <td><%= line_item['variant']["name"] %></td>
          <td><%= line_item['variant']['price'] %></td>
          <td><%= line_item["quantity"] %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Since `@items` is an array you will need to iterate it too, so two loops are needed: one for `@items` and one for `line_items`.

Although this solution should work, note that requesting a high number of orders could cause performance issues.

Comment: Thanks Gerry, I don't really understand how the order_number loop through in the url....or example let's say we have 3 orders:
R984044507, R601754941 and R036622716.
To get the line_items from each order, there should be a call to the URL with each order included in it. Example:
1st) http://localhost:4000/api/orders/R984044507.json?token=...
2) http://localhost:4000/api/orders/R601754941.json?token=...
3) http://localhost:4000/api/orders/R036622716.json?token=...

correct? I hard coded the 1st one in the URL in my question till I figure out how to loop the order numbers inside the URL

Comment: @Ignacio I fixed the answer, i forgot to replace the hardcoded order number; it should work fine now (e.g. make **3 calls** one with a each order in the URL).

Comment: thanks! that makes more sense....now I get:
undefined method `do' for #<Enumerator: ["R984044507", "R123456789", "R987654321"]:each>

Comment: @Ignacio Ohh, sorry, another typo in the controller, line 5: `orders.each.do |order|`; it should be `orders.each do |order|` (without the `.`). I've updated answer.

Comment: oh man, I read it 10 times and I missed it too.
Thanks a lot, it works like a charm!

Comment: @Ignacio Yeah, me too, it happens. Glad it worked! :)